# Converting a sting into an array when passing argument into a function

Tags: javascript

I need help converting the sting passed as an argument to the function into an array and then reversing the array.

I tried the code below, and it is not working.

```
function reverseString(str) {
  var arr = str.split(" ").reverse().join('');

  return arr;
}

reverseString("howdy");
```

Comment: Please learn how to use code blocks in question. I just put what you had in a code block to make it readable and you edited to remove the formatting

Comment: `"howdy"` does not contain `" "`.

Comment: The [`join()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp) method joins the elements of an array into a string.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 3):

Split by `""` not `" "`:

```js
function reverseString(str) { 
  var arr = str.split("").reverse().join("");
  return arr; 
}

console.log(reverseString("howdy"));
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the space in the split:
str.split("").reverse().join("")